# Download files from external s3 bucket using lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I want to use lambda to download backup files from external s3 account. I have got Access Key ID, Secret Access Key, Bucket Name and Region Name. And then synchronize it with my private s3 bucket.
Is it possible? And how?

Answer (score 1):

It appears your requirement is:

- Take data stored in `Bucket-A` in `Account-A`
- Copy it to `Bucket-B` in `Account-B`

The simplest way to do this is to use the `CopyObject()` command because it can directly transfer data between buckets (even between regions!) without needing to download & upload.

To do this, you will require one set of credentials that have Read permissions on `Bucket-A` and write permissions on `Bucket-B`. This can be either:

- An IAM `User-A` in `Account-A` that can read `Bucket-A` and a Bucket Policy on `Bucket-B` that permits `User-A` to write to `Bucket-B`, *OR*
- An IAM `User-B` in `Account-B` that can write to `Bucket-B` and a Bucket Policy on `Bucket-A` that permits Read access for `User-B`

Using the Bucket Policy means that one set of credentials can use the `CopyObject()` command to both Read & Write. Without that, you'd need to use one set of credentials to download an object and another set of credentials to upload the object. That's not a smart way to do it.

See: [Provide Cross-Account Access to Objects In S3 Buckets](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cross-account-access-s3/)

The easiest way to run the copy command is to use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) `aws s3 cp` or `aws s3 sync` commands. In your case, if you wish to synchronize the contents of files, you would use `aws s3 sync`.

A final option is to use [Cross-Region Replication - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/crr.html), but that only works on buckets in different regions. The buckets can belong to different AWS accounts.